# Can you see posts from users that your authenticated user is following in real time with the instagram api?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, social-media

I am trying to build an app that listens for all posts from people that a user follows and updates them on every post to their feed.  Is this possible with the instagram api?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't have realtime feeds for users that are followed by authenticated user. More details can be found [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/realtime/).